# PHP Max for multiple values to be displayed

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, sum, max

This is what i currently have:

```
$sum = array_count_values($_POST);
$max_value = max($sum);
$max_key = array_search($max_value, $sum);
```

$sum containes for example `A->2 B->6 C->4`
and `max($sum)` will then take 6, `$max_key` will get the key of that 6 (B in this case).

Now what if `$sum` is like this? `A->3 B->7 C->7`, that it takes `B->6` as the highest value.

I want `$max_key` to be an array containing both the letters B and C in this case
so i can use it in a foreach loop.

Thanks, Laurent

Comment: Just loop through `$sum` and add the keys with the highest value to an array.  array_search is looping through it anyway, it isn't doing magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want keys of max values from array try this,

```
$array = array("A" => 2,"B" => 7,"C" => "7");
$maxs_keys = array_keys($array, max($array));
print_r($maxs_keys);
```

[Codepad Demo.](http://codepad.org/ZVp0XkPn)

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP 5.3, then you can use conveniently array_filter like this:

`$sum = array( 'A'=>3, 'B'=>7, 'C'=>7 );
$max_value = max($sum);
$result = array_filter( $sum, function($x)  use ($max_value) { return $x === $max_value; } );
print_r($result);`

The snippet above will print what you want:
Array
(
    [B] => 7
    [C] => 7
)

If you want just the keys of the result, use array_keys to extract them.